# ghg.hs:45:1:parse error possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets

Tags: haskell

It's a program that you give 3 numbers and it needs to order them crescently, I also created the function three that multiplies numbers by 3. That's what I tried to do:

```
ordertriple :: (Integer, Integer, Integer) -> (Integer, Integer, Integer)
ordertriple (x, y, z) 
      | x < y && x < z && y < z = (three x, three y, three z)
      | x < y && x < z && z < y = (three x, three z, three y)
      | y < x && y < z && x < z = (three y, three x, three z)
      | y < x && y < z && z < x = (three y, three z, three x)
      | z < x && z < y && y < x = (three z, three x, three y)
      | otherwise               = (three z, three y, three x)
```

Answer (score 3):

you are missing the `(..)` around In`teger, Integer, Integer` and `x,y,z`:

```
orderTriple :: (Integer, Integer, Integer) -> (Integer, Integer, Integer)
orderTriple (x, y, z)
  | x < y && x < z && y < z = (three x, three y, three z)
  | x < y && x < z && z < y = (three x, three z, three y)
  | y < x && y < z && x < z = (three y, three x, three z)
  | y < x && y < z && z < x = (three y, three z, three x)
  | z < x && z < y && y < x = (three z, three x, three y)
  | otherwise             = (three z, three y, three x
```

should work

Comment: already did it and still not working still giving me the parse error xD @Carsten

Comment: once the typo in `orderTriple` (I somehow got in there) is fixed this will work if I copy&paste it straight from here to Haskell (and use some `three` - in my case `three = id`) - best guess: you have another *problem* in code we do not see

Answer (score 2):

Ordering things and multiplying them by three are completely independent operations. Write a function to order them *without* multiplying them by three.

Can you see how to do this using at most three comparisons?

As for your parse error, run GHC with `-fwarn-tabs`. If it warns you about tabs, use spaces instead.

Comment: This is a comment on his approach, not an answer to the question.

Comment: @chepner, I had an answer, but it was based on a misreading of the question. So I removed it promptly. I've now added advice on fixing based on their comment on Carsten's answer.

Comment: @chepner, I also believe in separating concerns *first*. Whether debugging a parse error, a type error, a runtime error, or a semantic error, it's easier to do it if you're working with smaller pieces.

Answer (score 2):

Your code runs fine for me but you'll get more reuse out of something like this:

```
orderedTriple :: (Num a, Ord a) => (a, a, a) -> (a, a, a)
orderedTriple = mapTriplet (* 3) . orderedTriplet

mapTriplet :: (a -> b) -> (a, a, a) -> (b, b, b)
mapTriplet f (x, y, z) = (f x, f y, f z)

orderedTriplet :: Ord a => (a, a, a) -> (a, a, a)
orderedTriplet (x, y, z)
    | x <= u    = (x, u, v)
    | x <= v    = (u, x, v)
    | otherwise = (u, v, x)
    where (u, v) = orderedPair (y, z)

orderedPair :: Ord a => (a, a) -> (a, a)
orderedPair (x, y)
    | x <= y    = (x, y)
    | otherwise = (y, x)
```